# Difference between findAll, getAll and list in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

With Grails there are several ways to do the same thing.

Finds all of domain class instances:

```
Book.findAll()
Book.getAll()
Book.list()
```

Retrieves an instance of the domain class for the specified id:

```
Book.findById(1)
Book.get(1)
```

When do you use each one? Are there significant differences in performance?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`getAll` is an enhanced version of `get` that takes multiple ids and returns a `List` of instances. The list size will be the same as the number of provided ids; any misses will result in a `null` at that slot. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getAll.html

`findAll` lets you use HQL queries and supports pagination, but they're not limited to instances of the calling class so I use `executeQuery` instead. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html

`list` finds all instances and supports pagination. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html

`get` retrieves a single instance by id. It uses the *instance* cache, so multiple calls within the same Hibernate session will result in at most one database call (e.g. if the instance is in the 2nd-level cache and you've enabled it).

`findById` is a dynamic finder, like `findByName`, `findByFoo`, etc. As such it does not use the instance cache, but can be cached if you have query caching enabled (typically not a good idea). `get` should be preferred since its caching is a lot smarter; cached query results (even for a single instance like this) are pessimistically cleared more often than you would expect, but the instance cache doesn't need to be so pessimistic.

The one use case I would have for `findById` is as a security-related check, combined with another property. For example instead of retrieving a `CreditCard` instance using `CreditCard.get(cardId)`, I'd find the currently logged-in user and use `CreditCard.findByIdAndUser(cardId, user)`. This assumes that `CreditCard` has a `User user` property. That way both properties have to match, and this would block a hacker from accessing the card instance since the card id might match, but the user wouldn't.

Answer (score 12):

Another difference between Domain.findByID(id) and Domain.get(id) is that if you're using a hibernate filter, you need to use Domain.findById(id). Domain.get(id) bypasses the filter.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, these are all identical

```
Book.findAll()
Book.getAll()
Book.list()
```

These will return the same results

```
Book.findById(1)
Book.get(1)
```

but `get(id)` will use the cache (if enabled), so should be preferred to `findById(1)`

Comment: However, if you're using a hibernate filter , you need to use Book.findById(). Book.get() bypasses the filter.