# Grails strange removeFrom* behavior

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I just encountered a strange behaviour when deleting a object from a `hasMany`Relation in grails 2.2.1.

Deleting is **not working** with:

```
def lessonInstance = Lesson.get(lessonId)  
long id = Long.valueOf(taskId)  
def task = Task.get(id)  
lessonInstance.removeFromTasks(task)
```

While deleting **is working** with:

```
def lessonInstance = Lesson.get(lessonId)  
long id = Long.valueOf(taskId)      
def task = lessonInstance.tasks.find { it.id == id }  
lessonInstance.removeFromTasks(task)
```

I expected both to work and I am now curious why the latter works and the first does not work. Here are the Domain classes envolved:

```
class Lesson{  
    static hasMany = [tasks:Task]  
    static hasOne = [skill:Skill]       
       static constraints = {  
        tasks(nullable: false, minSize: 1)  
        skill(nullable: true)
    }  
}

class Task extends Artefact{

    Integer experiencePoints=0

    Integer credits=0

    static constraints = {
        experiencePoints(blank: false, min: 0)
        credits(blank: false, min: 0)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like Grails is not picking up the fact that `Task` loaded with `get()` and with `Lesson.tasks` is the same object.

BTW I wonder if `Task` or `Artefact` have `equals()/hashCode()` redefined.

Comment: If `Artefact` is a domain object (table per subclass strategy), can you try using `def task = Artefact.get(id)` in the former case.

Comment: Just an FYI - `blank:false` is doing nothing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go read: http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/ as it explains why you have to do a little more, to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem might be due to the caching differences between get and find. See Burt Beckwith's answer for [Difference between findAll, getAll and list in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907881/difference-between-findall-getall-and-list-in-grails).

...I tried to replicate the problem using the grails console but both find and get approaches seemed to work.