# grails - org.hibernate.QueryException (could not resolve property)

Tags: grails, hql

I'm trying to get the list of a specific rental from the current user.

Code in controller:

```
def index() { 
if (isLoggedIn()) {
    String username = getPrincipal().username

    def accountInstance = Account.findByUsername(username)
    def rentalInstanceList = Rental.findAll("from Rental as r where r.account_id=:accountid", [accountid: accountInstance.id])
    }
}
```

account_id is a foreign key.

After running I get the error:

```
could not resolve property: account_id of: ers.Rental
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can we see your Rental domain class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in HQL you have to use the field names as defined in your domain classes. So, your query should look like:

```
def list = Rental.findAll("from Rental where accountId=:accountid", [accountid: accountInstance.id])
```

or

```
def list = Rental.findAllByAccount accountInstance
```

or even

```
def list = Rental.findAllByAccount getPrincipal()
```

if the return type of `getPrincipal()` has the `id` field.

Answer (score -1):

findAll is not limited to instances of the calling class so I use executeQuery instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916483/5011228